# Why was not the table created from array of data from "LocalStorage"?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I want to create a table from the data that is in the `localStorage`. To do this, implemented the adding method: `addToBook ()`. `removeContact (e)` and removing  method from which I send datas to `localStorage`.

**But I get two errors:**

- First: `Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'innerHTML' of
  indefinite`
- And the second when adding a contact: `Uncaught ReferenceError:
  LocalStorage is not defined`

I need that the data be correctly added / deleted to the array and `localStorage`. Also, what would this data be created or deleted in the table, which is what I'm trying to do in the method: `drowTable ()`. Help please solve this problem

```js
class Contacts {
    constructor() {
        // Storage Array
        this.contacts = [];
    }

    addToBook() {
        let isNull = forms.name.value != '' && forms.phone.value != '' && 
forms.email.value != '';
        if (isNull) {
            // format the input into a valid JSON structure
            let obj = new LocalStorage(forms.name.value, forms.phone.value, 
forms.email.value);
            this.contacts.push(obj);
            localStorage["addbook"] = JSON.stringify(this.contacts);
            table.show();
        }
        console.log(this.contacts);
    }

    removeContact(e) {
        // Remove an entry from the addressbook
        if (e.target.classList.contains('delete')) {
            let remID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
            this.contacts.splice(remID, 1);
            localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(this.contacts);
            table.show();
        }
    }
}
let data = new Contacts();
class Forms {
    constructor() {
        // Blocks
        this.BookDiv = document.querySelector('.addbook');
        // Forms
        this.fields = document.forms[0].elements;
        this.name = this.fields[0].value;
        this.phone = this.fields[1].value;
        this.email = this.fields[2].value;
        // Buttons
        this.addBtn = document.getElementById("Add");
        this.addBtn.addEventListener("click", data.addToBook.bind(data));
        this.BookDiv.addEventListener("click", data.removeContact.bind(data))

    }
}
class ShowAddressBook {
    constructor() {
    };

    drowTable() {
        if (localStorage['addbook'] === undefined) {
            localStorage['addbook'] = '';
        } else {
            data.contacts = JSON.parse(localStorage['addbook']);
            // Loop over the array addressBook and insert into the page
            data.BookDiv.innerHTML = '';
            const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#book .data");
            for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                const e = rows.item(i);
                e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
            }
            const table = document.getElementById("shop");

            for (let i = 0; i < data.contacts.length; i++) {
                //create table
                table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data">
                    <td class="checkBox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>${data.contacts[i].name}</td>
                    <td>${data.contacts[i].phone}</td>
                    <td>${data.contacts[i].email}</td>
                    <td ><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-id="' + i + '"></i></td>
                </tr></tbody>`;
            }

        }
        this.drowTable();
        console.log(data.contacts);
    }
}
let table = new ShowAddressBook();
let forms = new Forms();
table.drowTable();

class LocalStorage {
    constructor(name, phone, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div class="AddNewContact">
        <i class="fas fa-search "></i>
    </div>
    <div class="addNewContact-form">
        <form name="register">
        <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" class="formFields">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label><input type="text" id="phone" class="formFields">
        <label for="email">E-Mail</label><input type="text" id="email" class="formFields">
        <br><br>
        <button id="Add" type="button">Add Now</button><button id="Cancel" type="button">Cancel</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="addbook">
             <table id="book">
                 <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th class="check"></th>
                     <th class="name">Name: <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v"></i></th>
                     <th class="phone">Phone: <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v"></i></th>
                     <th class="email">E-mail: <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt-v"></i></th>
                     <th class="del"></th>
                 </tr>
                 </thead>
             </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: `localStorage["addbook"]` is incorrect. You may mean `localStorage.setItem("addbook",JSON.stringify(this.contacts))` - it is not recommended to create an object called LocalsStorage since it is confusing  - your LocalStorage is unrelated to built-in localStorage - please read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Second error `data.BookDiv.innerHTML` you cannot store and retrieve a div using stringify. Instead store the ID of the div

Comment: You have a syntax error it's should be `localStorage` and not `LocalStorage`. It's case sensitive. Second

Comment: @Aminadav he has an class constructor called LocalStorage